# Is it possible to copy a portion of a file using SSH?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, scp

I want to download a the end of a log file from my dev machine at home to my local machine, the last 1MB. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could get the last 1MB from the file and save it as another file. Then scp that file to your local machine.
You can extract the data by using:

```
tail -c $(( 1024*1024 )) your_file > target_file
```

(source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/use-dd-to-cut-file-end-part)

Comment: Thanks, I used this solution in in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Run it on your dev machine

```
tail -c 1048576 logfile.log  | ssh  user@remotemachine "cat > local_file_name"
```

Comment: When you say "run this on dev" that would be the remote machine. I'm sitting behind a router on the local machine so I'm unable to SSH to it. I can SSH from local to remote/dev. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I assumed that dev is remote and you have ssh access to local from dev. IF you ar at the local and remote dont have ssh access to local then you need to run this on local 
    `ssh user@remote 'tail -c 1048576 logfile.log' > local_file`